# Настройка отображения данных в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю программку, наверно правильно Parser называется.

Собирает различные данные с сайта, производит вычисления, формирует стек данных и выдаёт в TextBox.

В TextBox, не совсем удобно читается и хочется как то сделать всё удобнее.

Вот как можно, такие стеки данных , выдавать примерно так ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В идеале, если какие то стеки мне не нравятся , то удалять/скрывать по кнопке и их место заполнит предыдущий.

С textBox это выглядит так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проще использовать `wpf`, чем настраивать `winforms`

Comment: @FoggyFinder какие элементы WPF мне подойдут для этого ? Перекинуть код наверно не сложно будет.
Я пробовал искать информацию по WPF , но что то её совсем нет на RU

Comment: Какие элементы? Например, `ListBox`/`ListVew`/`ItemsControl` - `wpf` позволяет легко настраивать внешний вид

Comment: @FoggyFinder спс , пробую разобраться, есть какие то RU видео на примете для начального ознакомления ?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, поменяли тэг на [winforms], а ответ будет "делайте это на WPF" ? Ну, если так, то тэг [winforms] будет не актуален же?

Comment: @4per нет, на winforms тоже так можно, но намного сложнее. Вопрос в том, как это сделать на winforms, а не в том, как вообще это можно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементарно:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel;

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();

            tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Fill, ColumnCount = 3 };

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var panel = new MyPanel
                {
                    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                    Title = "Title" + i,
                    Content = "Text" + i
                };
                tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(panel);
            }

            tableLayoutPanel.Click += TableLayoutPanel_Click;
        }

        private void TableLayoutPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var panel = new MyPanel { Title = "Added", Content = "Some content" };
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(panel); // добавляем в конец
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(panel, 0); // переносим в начало
        }
    }

    public class MyPanel : Panel
    {
        private Panel topPanel;
        private Button closeButton;
        private Label titleLabel;
        private TextBox contentTextBox;

        public MyPanel()
        {
            contentTextBox = new TextBox { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Multiline = true };

            topPanel = new Panel { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top, Height = 20 };
            closeButton = new Button { Parent = topPanel, Text = "\u274C", Dock = DockStyle.Right, Width = 20, BackColor = Color.Red, FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup };
            titleLabel = new Label { Parent = topPanel, BackColor = Color.Green, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

            closeButton.Click += CloseButton_Click;
        }

        private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Parent?.Controls.Remove(this);
        }

        public string Title { get => titleLabel.Text; set => titleLabel.Text = value; }
        public string Content { get => contentTextBox.Text; set => contentTextBox.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Вместо `TableLayoutPanel` можно использовать `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Классу `MyPanel` (то, что вы называете "стек", хотя стек - это контейнер для данных, а не одна запись, по идее) можно наваять любой внешний вид.

---

При старте приложения создаются и добавляются 10 кастомных панелей. Их можно удалять кликом на крестик.

Добавлять новые панели можно кликом на сам `TableLayoutPanel` (сделано для простоты).

Comment: Wow всё подробно, спасибо ! Под "стеком" я имел в виду , пачку переменных выведенную разом на экран. И таких стеков полно, появляется в режиме онлайн. Вот и хотелось что-бы удобнее было читать то, что находится в переменных.

Comment: А можно панели MyPanel наваять внешний вид через сам WinForms визуализатор или только через код ?

Comment: @Vipz - можно. Нужно наследоваться от [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx). Могу посоветовать книгу Павла Агурова "Разработка компонентов в MS Visual Studio 2005/2008".